# Why can't "create database if not exists" using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I wrote some lines to `create database if not exists` according to the sample:

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/98164/sqlalchemy_utils.database_exists

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database
db_user = 'postgres'
db_pass = 'xxxxxx'
db_ip = '127.0.0.1'
db_name = 'mydb'
engine = create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}/{}/'.format(db_user,db_pass,db_ip,db_name))
if not database_exists(engine.url): create_database(engine.url)
```

It encounter the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/database.py", line 569, in create_database
    quote(engine, database),
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/orm.py", line 528, in quote
    dialect = get_bind(mixed).dialect
  File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/orm.py", line 339, in get_bind
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: This method accepts only Session, Engine, Connection and declarative model objects.
```

How to fix it then?

Comment: Are you using SA 2.0? Maybe it has some breaking changes, looks like they had to fix a lot for 1.4 - https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/pull/506

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by upgrading:

```
pip  install  --upgrade  sqlalchemy-utils
Found existing installation: SQLAlchemy-Utils 0.39.0
Uninstalling SQLAlchemy-Utils-0.39.0:
  Successfully uninstalled SQLAlchemy-Utils-0.39.0
Successfully installed sqlalchemy-utils-0.41.1
```

Re-run the previous `if not database_exists(engine.url): create_database(engine.url)`,success!